# How do I set a Photoshop document/template for bleeds?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

This flyer is almost accepted on Themeforest, but I got one problem: I got message from reviewer: "Please do some research on setting up a document for bleeds. Look at info on printing to understand what needs to happen with artwork to ensure the design is sset up right for printing".

The actual file is 8.5 x 11 inches, should it have a 0.25 inch bleed, and actually measure 8.75 x 11.25 inches?

[Here is my PSD file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u03nwcvyiwfxm9e/Flyer-Creative%20Business%20-1%20-%20Copy.psd?dl=0) which I measured as print:

And [here is my image preview](http://s27.postimg.org/oc113ibkz/Capture.jpg).

Comment: The PSD document is simply a white document with guides. Not sure how that's supposed to help explain your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. What do you mean by 'printable'? Do you mean your ink jet printer? Sending off to a printer to be offset printed?

Answer (score 3):

To have .25 inch bleeds, your document size in Photoshop would have to be 9 inches (8.5 + .25 + .25) by 11.5 inches (11 + .25 + .25), so you'll have to correct the dimensions. At the moment, you are set up for 1/8th inch bleed, not 1/4.

Artwork must extend all the way to the edge of the bleed area. Right now, you have *no bleed* in your document, because the artwork stops at the trim edge, not the bleed. You should have no white margins in your submitted template.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for your valuable comment. yes, i got some idea that you recommended me. ok, i will try implement your idea and let you know :)

Comment: Hi Alan, yes, i have bleed .25in that would have extend with white color background. finally,I have updated my flyer. would you please check it is everything ok.

http://s15.postimg.org/lkp2aubmj/Capture.jpg

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're still leave a white border round the artwork. That should not be there. All of your colored panels must extend to the edge of the canvas.

Comment: Hi Alan,Thanks for your reply.yes, may be i got it what you recommened me. would you please check it out again and please let me know is everything ok? http://s21.postimg.org/xohhtx21j/Capture.jpg

Comment: Hi Alan, Thansk for your help. yes, design accepted and now on Graphic River.here is go:
http://goo.gl/86VSLe